# Finding vector fields on $S^2$ with equal divergence

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathfrak{X}_{CK}^{\perp}$ be the space of vector fields on $S^2$ that are $L^2$-orthogonal to conformal Killing vector fields. Let $\mathfrak{X}_{CK}$ be the 6-dimensional space of conformal Killing vector fields on $S^2$.

Can we find a vector field $Y \in \mathfrak{X}_{CK}^{\perp}$  and a vector field $W \in \mathfrak{X}_{CK}$ that is not Killing such that

$$\mathrm{div}(Y) = \mathrm{div}(W)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this is not possible:

Per my comment on [Divergence of conformal Killing vector fields on $S^2$ and the spherical harmonics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410824/divergence-of-conformal-killing-vector-fields-on-s2-and-the-spherical-harmoni?noredirect=1#comment1054264_410824) you want to solve
$$
\textrm{div} (Y) = -2a\cdot x
$$
for $Y$ orthogonal to conformal-KVF's and $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ fixed (nonzero). Suppose you can do this. Then, we find that
$$
Y = a^T + W
$$
for $W$ divergence free. From this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898371/divergence-free-vector-field-on-a-2-sphere you can see that $W = J \nabla f$ for some function $f \in C^\infty(S^2)$ (for $J$ the complex structure on $S^2$). Now, by assumption, $Y$ is orthogonal to $a^T$:
\begin{align*}
0 & = \int_{S^2} Y\cdot a^T \\
& = \int_{S^2}|a^T|^2 + (J \nabla f) \cdot a^T \\
& = \int_{S^2}|a^T|^2 -   \nabla f \cdot J a^T \\
& = \int_{S^2}|a^T|^2 + f \textrm{div}(J a^T). 
\end{align*}
However, note that $Ja^T$ is a KVF and thus divergence free. This implies that $\int_{S^2}|a^T|^2 = 0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: You helped me many times. Thank you!