# Divergence of conformal Killing vector fields on $S^2$ and the spherical harmonics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, special-functions, conformal-geometry

Can anyone think of a conformal Killing vector field $W$ on $S^2$ with the round metric that is not Killing such that its divergence is $L^2$-orthogonal to the spherical harmonics with $\ell = 1$?

One conformal Killing vector field is $W = \sin(\phi) \partial_{\phi}$, but we have

\begin{align}
\int_{S^2} \mathrm{div}(W) \, \, Y^{m=0}_{\ell=1} &= \int_{S^2} \mathrm{div}(W) \cos(\phi)\\
&=-\int_{S^2} W \cdot d(\cos(\phi))\\
&= \int_{S^2}\sin^2(\phi) \neq 0
\end{align}

We know that we can find three orthogonal conformal Killing vector fields $W_1,...,W_3$. Is it the case that we can choose $W_1$,...,$W_3$ so that their divergence coincides with the three spherical harmonics with $\ell = 1$? (if yes, then the answer to my first question is no).

Comment: Any conformal-KVF is $K + a^T$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}^3$ constant and $K$ a KVF. You can check that $\textrm{Div}_{S^2}(K+a^T) = - 2 a \cdot x$ which is a first spherical harmonic.

Comment: @OtisChodosh Thank you :) 
How do we see that every conformal KVF is of the form $K + a^T$?
It looks like the other way around is true too: for any $F$ that is a linear combination of $Y^{-1}_{1}, Y^0_1, Y^1_1$, there exists a unique conformal KVF with divergence equal $F$. Is that correct?

Comment: You know the dimension of the space of conformal KVF is 6, right? Given this, $K+a^T$ generates a $6$ dimensional space of KVF, so the dimensions match up. By $Y^{-1}_1$ etc you mean 1-st spherical harmonics, right? If so, then any 1-st spherical harmonic is $a^T$ for some $a$, so the answer is yes.